# How to reset UITextView height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I've a chat screen where I've `UITextView` below table view. I've set `UITextView` height to <= 150 in IB. I'm letting this text view resize and scroll as I type text.

After I send message and reload table view the height of text view remains 150 and doesn't reset to it's original size.

How do I reset this height after reloading table?

I've tried following solution after sending message which resets text view height but breaks auto height change when I type in text view again.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
//....
self.textViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.textView.contentSize.height
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conform the UITextViewDelegate and implement textViewDidChange:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGFloat minHeight = 30;
    CGFloat maxHeight = 150;
    CGFloat height = ceil([textView.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : textView.font}].height);
    if(height < minHeight){
        height = minHeight;
    }else if (height > maxHeight){
        height = maxHeight;
    }
    self.textViewHeightConstraint.constant = height;
}
```

Comment: This will not work as textViewDidChange will not be called after message is sent. My problem is after sending the message and reloading the tableview above  text view the text view doesn't reset it's height.

Comment: After sending the message, reset the TextView.text and call textViewDidChange